# Intermittent error when creating System.Windows.Media.Pen in Xunit tests

Tags: wpf, xunit.net

I have a bunch of Xunit tests that work most of the time, but then sometime fail when calling the code listed below.  The tests fail together as a bunch, though not necessarily all of them that share the affected code. If I run them again, they will most likely all pass and I won't see the error again for a few test runs.

The tests all fail with something similar to:

```
Message: 
    System.IndexOutOfRangeException : Index was outside the bounds of the array.
  Stack Trace: 
    ArrayItemList`1.EntryAt(Int32 index)
    FrugalObjectList`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
    Freezable.AddContextToList(DependencyObject context, DependencyProperty property)
    Freezable.AddContextInformation(DependencyObject context, DependencyProperty property)
    Freezable.AddInheritanceContext(DependencyObject context, DependencyProperty property)
    DependencyObject.ProvideSelfAsInheritanceContext(DependencyObject doValue, DependencyProperty dp)
    DependencyObject.ProvideSelfAsInheritanceContext(Object value, DependencyProperty dp)
    DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
    DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
    DependencyObject.SetValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
    Pen.ctor(Brush brush, Double thickness)
    CanvasPathDrawer.CreateOutlinePen() line 194
```

The code it fails on is

```
private Pen CreateOutlinePen()
{
    var outlinePenBrush = CreateOutlinePenBrush(OutlineType.None);

    var outlinePen = new Pen(outlinePenBrush, 1) // Fails on this line
    {
        EndLineCap = PenLineCap.Round,
        DashCap = PenLineCap.Round,
        LineJoin = PenLineJoin.Round,
        StartLineCap = PenLineCap.Round,
        MiterLimit = 10.0
    };

    return outlinePen;
}

private static Brush CreateOutlinePenBrush(OutlineType outlineType)
{
    switch (outlineType)
    {
        case OutlineType.None:
            return OutlineTypeNoneBrush;
        // etc
    }
}

public static Brush OutlineTypeNoneBrush { get; } = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
```

The tests are running on the STA thread using the [StaFact] attribute.

I imagine that I have missed something fundamental about how I am creating the object.  Should I be creating a new brush each time maybe?